# Retrieving a list of passwords for local accounts on windows 10 machines

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a large number of systems that have multiple local user accounts but were built at different times using a variety of passwords.  They are all on the same domain and are all in active directory.  Is there a way to be able to write a PowerShell script to use a .csv file to reach out to each machine and retrieve a list of the local user accounts as well as the passwords that they currently have set to each account?

Comment: No. Passwords are hashed (one-way encrypted) before they're stored, so the plaintext password isn't even present on the machine.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is there a way to force an over-write on those passwords?  Were trying to change all local admin passwords to the same across the board but the machines are spread out all over the place

Comment: Yes, there is! Install [LAPS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46899) on the machines - this will allow you to use group policy to control the frequency with which local admin passwords are automatically rotated, you can also set it up to write the passwords back to active directory so you can keep track of them